# flickr callback URL not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, callback, flickr

I downloaded the objective c flickr library from the link. https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

Created the app key and secret and updated the SampleApiKey.h file. The callback URL in flicker app page is set as snapnrun://myapp and same in application URL scheme. I am running the SnapAndRun example application from the downloaded source. After running the app(both in simulator and device same behaviour), when i tap on authorize button, it takes me to web based authorization page in safari. When i click authorize app button there, safari is not taking me back to the application.

Am i missing something more here, or is there any change in flickr API in last couple of days, so that the call back authorization doenst work??

But the official flickr app is working fine. Tried in the device. After authorization, it goes back to flickr app.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Post relevant lines from your Info.plist for the custom URL handler, as well as your AppDelegate code for handling the custom URL object.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and I found out that when I tried calling the flickr API via xmlrpc request, but when I tried with JSON it worked.
Hope that work for you also..

Comment: I didnt used that framework.. I just used the API endpoint and calling it with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your key and secret, below that, there is an option to `Edit Authentication Flow`. Pass the callback URL there.